# Catched exception in parent thread interrupting its flow when child process fails

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, architecture, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I got an scenario like following.

MainClass

```
event.addListener(Event e){
  if (e == EXPECTED_EVENT) 
      Future<?> result = executorService.submit(myTask);
  }
}
doSomething()
doSomethingElse()
doMoreStuff()
```

Is there any way to interrupt the main flow in case one of the tasks fails?

I don't know where and how exactly synchronize the Exception part:

```
    try {
        Object result = ((Future<?>) expectedFutureTask).get();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e ) { /* Task was interupted/stopped */}
    catch (CancellationException e) { /* Task was cancelled */} 
    catch (ExecutionException e) { //Task threw an Exception
        throw e.getCause();
    }
```

Any clean design to this need?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the problem is. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I put a main class, which submits tasks to an executionService via listener., Then I ask "Is there any way to interrupt the main flow in case one of the tasks fails?". I thought it was pretty clear, what do you not understand?

Comment: The code you show interrupts the main flow. Is that now what you want? There is no magical way to make code go about it's business but suddenly throw an InterrruptedByFailingChildTaskException and then go into an exception handler. Your main code needs to check (from time to time / constantly) if a condition is met that needs action.  You can make an executor (or listenable future) that calls the `Thread.interrupt()` method of the parent thread but the problem remains, you need to do something that checks the interrupted condition.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was asking !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), it allows you to compose tasks as a DAG, execute them sync or async as needed and merge results/exceptions.

Interrupting of the futures in the graph can then be accomplished by [canceling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) them.

Comment: Awesome eye-opener, I'm studying it, if it fits my needs I'll check it